# How to change a tab bar item from the tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I got tab bar controller with three view controllers setup. One of those view controllers changes its tab bar item badgeValue when I open it. I would like to change this badgeValue already when I arrive at the first tab.

I created a Tabbarcontoller: UITabBarController class but don't know how to easily access the items of the sub views. Here is the code from my Tabbarcontoller class:

```
    class TabBarController: UITabBarController, MainMethodsDelegate {

    var myFriendsRequests: [UserInfo] = []
    var friendRequestsCount: Int = 0

    func getFriendsRequests_Methods_Destination(myFriendsRequest: UserInfo) {
        myFriendsRequests.append(myFriendsRequest)
        self.friendRequestsCount = myFriendsRequests.count

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //friendsBarItem.badgeValue = String(self.friendRequestsCount)
        }
    }

    let mainMethods = MainMethods()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainMethods.delegate = self
        mainMethods.getFriendsRequests()

    }
}
```

And here the working code from the sub view controller:

```
class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, MainMethodsDelegate {

    var myFriendsRequests: [UserInfo] = []
    var friendRequestsCount: Int = 0

    func getFriendsRequests_Methods_Destination(myFriendsRequest: UserInfo) {
        myFriendsRequests.append(myFriendsRequest)
        self.friendRequestsCount = myFriendsRequests.count

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.friendsBarItem.badgeValue = String(self.friendRequestsCount)
        }

    }

    let mainMethods = MainMethods()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainMethods.delegate = self
        mainMethods.getFriendsRequests()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var friendsBarItem: UITabBarItem!

}
```

I'm looking for a simple way to access the sub view controllers or at least the bar items where it says:

```
//friendsBarItem.badgeValue = String(self.friendRequestsCount)
```

I'm not sure if delegates is the right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quite simple way to access the barItems. I only had to access the array of tabBar items with:

`tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = ""`

Here is my code for the UITabBarController:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, MainMethodsDelegate {

    var myFriendsRequests: [UserInfo] = []
    var friendRequestsCount: Int = 0

    func getFriendsRequests_Methods_Destination(myFriendsRequest: UserInfo) {
        myFriendsRequests.append(myFriendsRequest)
        self.friendRequestsCount = myFriendsRequests.count

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = String(self.friendRequestsCount)

        }
    }

    let mainMethods = MainMethods()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainMethods.delegate = self
        mainMethods.getFriendsRequests()
    }
}
```

The sub view controller does not need to check and update the badgeValue anymore. (This is fine in my case since the `getFriendsRequests_Methods_Destination(myFriendsRequest: UserInfo)` method gets triggered as soon as there is a new friends request anyways using a (Firestore) snapshot listener.)

My initial way was to access the tabItem from each of the sub view controllers individually using `tabBarController!.tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = ""` But this would have been redundant in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the bar item out of the friends controller. It does not need to know about the tabBar. If I were you, I would create a protocol to let know your tabBarController that the number of friend requests has changed.

First, define the protocol:

```
protocol FriendsRequestDelegate {
    func friendsRequestsDidChange(number: Int)
}
```

Then, add the variable to your FriendsViewController:

```
weak var delegate: FriendsRequestDelegate?
```

And, we need to trigger that func, still in FriendsViewController, after fetching the number of friends request, add;

```
delegate?.friendsRequestsDidChange(number: myFriendsRequests.count)
```

Finally, make your TabBarController conform to this protocol;

```
extension TabBarController: FriendsRequestDelegate {

   func friendsRequestsDidChange(number: Int) {
       friendsBarItem.badgeValue = String(number)
   }

}
```

See what I mean? This way your friendsRequestController doesn't know about the tabBar and it'll keep your code clean.

Comment: Thanks you for your solution, however I think I found a way which is much simpler and since I only need to access the barItems it is sufficient for me.